# Entity Framework Core mistaking SQL Date as a string

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, portable-class-library, .net-standard

I am using Entity Framework Core within a Xamarin PCL app to work with a remote SQL Database. One of the database fields is a nullable `Date`. I have generated a model for the table, and this is the property being used:

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdated { get; set; }
```

The date is formatted in the table as follows: `2009-04-22`

For whatever reason, when the object is loaded from the table, it throws an error stating that it expected a `DateTime?` but received a `string` instead:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception occured while reading a database value for property 'Item.LastUpdated'. The expected type was 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]' but the actual value was of type 'System.String'.
```

My guess is that it has to do with the way the date is formatted, but I don't know for sure.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

EDIT: **StackTrace**

```
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.ThrowReadValueException[TValue] (System.Exception exception, System.Object value, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IPropertyBase property) [0x0008f] in <2645c1c7345546f5b968e91de81e2b12>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.TryReadValue[TValue] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer valueBuffer, System.Int32 index, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IPropertyBase property) [0x00012] in <2645c1c7345546f5b968e91de81e2b12>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.UnbufferedEntityShaper`1[TEntity].Shape (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext queryContext, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer valueBuffer) [0x0003e] in <1ce4ae811dd94fe5a5e10e630f2f4c7a>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider+<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1[T].MoveNext () [0x0005c] in <1ce4ae811dd94fe5a5e10e630f2f4c7a>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Boolean& found) [0x00045] in <cc41d889a5b24501ae882a5cc55746dd>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00000] in <cc41d889a5b24501ae882a5cc55746dd>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler+<>c__DisplayClass20_0`1[TResult].<CompileQueryCore>b__0 (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext qc) [0x00074] in <2645c1c7345546f5b968e91de81e2b12>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult] (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression query) [0x00029] in <2645c1c7345546f5b968e91de81e2b12>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult] (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression) [0x00000] in <2645c1c7345546f5b968e91de81e2b12>:0 
  at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource] (System.Linq.IQueryable`1[T] source) [0x0002f] in <cc41d889a5b24501ae882a5cc55746dd>:0 
  at BMobile.Pages.LoginPage.PerformLogin (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x0003a] in C:\Users\rwilde\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\BMobile\BMobile\BMobile\Pages\LoginPage.cs:44
```

**Target Site**

{Void ThrowReadValueException[Nullable`1](System.Exception, System.Object, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IPropertyBase)}

Comment: What type has the column on the DB?

Comment: The Database column type is 'Date'

Comment: Am curious if this is an issue with EF Core or Xamarin.  EF 6 (.NET Framework) handles `date` column to `DateTime` field mapping well.

Comment: Might be a provider bug. Which of the 3 MySQL providers for EF Core are you using?

Comment: I would try to use a datetime2 column, that may help, but what you really should do is NOT to connect to a remote database directly, anyone can hack the application and gain access to it, the ideal is to create a middleware, something like a REST api and then do the queries there.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change any database columns, as it will break other products. I'm using EF Core 1.1.2 with EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer to connect to the remote database. The odd thing is, there are other columns in the database (that come before the problem column) that use a nullable `date` as well, and those are parsed just fine.

Comment: Perhaps providing a full exception, with a complete stack trace would help. Then we could see which method is failing.

Comment: Have you tried to manually read the database with a data reader and ensure the field type is the one you think? If other fields with the same type read correctly is more than probable there's no bug but just a human error.

Comment: Yep, SQL Management Studio lists it as a `date` as well. I've added a StackTrace to the original post as well, although it isn't of much help.

Comment: Can you copy the table DDL to an empty database to create a small, complete repro?